# SQS Queue purge operation fails with exception

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-sqs, boto3

This issue pertains to AWS services and the python boto API

I send messages on a the queue. Eventually, I need to manage the deletion or the purging of messages on the queue.

The code below, sometimes it doesn't give exception, and sometimes it does. The idea is to attempt to purge, if there is no message in the queue, to just continue safely without aborting my program.

```
sqs = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(awsRegion)
sqsQueue =  sqs.lookup(sqsQueueName)
if sqsQueue != None:
    try:
        status=sqsQueue.purge()
        return status
    except ValueError as e:
        print e
        pass

else:
    print 'No messages in the Queue %s ' % sqsQueueName
```

How do I ensure that even if the purge command returns an exception I safely continue.

The error I get is the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File "C:.......\ to a
>   script.py", line 143, in purgeQueue 
>       status=sqsQueue.purge()    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\sqs\queue.py", line 396, in purge 
>       return self.connection.purge_queue(self)    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\sqs\connection.py", line 124, in
>   purge_queue 
>       return self.get_status('PurgeQueue', None, queue.id)    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line 1227, in
>   get_status 
>       raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)  boto.exception.SQSError: SQSError: 403 Forbidden  Sender`AWS.SimpleQueueService.PurgeQueueInProgress`Only one PurgeQueue operation on mcUplinkQueue is allowed every 60
>   seconds.e465d563-f71a-5f1b-9760-84feb0bd315b

Comment: @MarkB don't care about the message, I'm interested in continuing my program. The current implementation when there is no message on the queue, the purge operation raises an exception that stops my program. pass doesn't do it

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  I added above the exception I get.  Maybe this has something to do with the fact that if you do multiple purges on the same queue within small period of time, it throws this error. The reason I say this, is because when I do it after a while it doesn't throw it, if I do tow consecutive purging ...this exception is thrown. Either way how can I make this, not abort my program

Comment: Yes, this is the cause.  You cannot purge a queue more often than approximately every 60 seconds.  I know the native AWS APIs, not Python, so I'm speculating here, but it looks like you are trying to catch a `ValueError` exception, but this is a `ResponseError` exception.  You're not catching what's being thrown, so it's fatal, right?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  So, i guess there is no way to this gracefully, and continue with the program rather than crash